# Authentication failure while connecting to Tibco topic through Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, authentication, tibco-topic

I am trying to listen to messages coming through a Tibco topic in my spring boot application. My config looks like this -

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class TibcoConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        TopicConnectionFactory factory = new TibjmsTopicConnectionFactory("TIBCO_BROKER_URL");
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setClientId("client1");
        factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter authenticationConnectionFactory() {
        UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter = new UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter();
        userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setTargetConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setUsername("USERNAME");
        userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter.setPassword("PASSWORD");
        return userCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter;
    }
}
```

And my listener looks like this -

```
@Component
public class TibcoRequestListener {

    @JmsListener(destination = "TIBCO_TOPIC_NAME", containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
    public void receiveMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            TextMessage txtMsg = (TextMessage) message;
            System.out.println("Received response: " + txtMsg.getText());
            System.out.println("Message type: " + message.getJMSType());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Error log -

```
2020-07-08 18:28:37.711  WARN 3552 --- [)-10.110.74.130] o.s.boot.actuate.jms.JmsHealthIndicator  : JMS health check failed

javax.jms.JMSSecurityException: authentication failed
    at com.tibco.tibjms.Tibjmsx.buildException(Tibjmsx.java:575) ~[tibjms-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnection._create(TibjmsConnection.java:1330) ~[tibjms-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnection.<init>(TibjmsConnection.java:4115) ~[tibjms-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsTopicConnection.<init>(TibjmsTopicConnection.java:36) ~[tibjms-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxCFImpl._createImpl(TibjmsxCFImpl.java:191) ~[tibjms-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsxCFImpl._createConnection(TibjmsxCFImpl.java:253) ~[tibjms-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at com.tibco.tibjms.TibjmsConnectionFactory.createConnection(TibjmsConnectionFactory.java:36) ~[tibjms-5.1.0.jar:5.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.jms.JmsHealthIndicator.doHealthCheck(JmsHealthIndicator.java:52) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator.health(AbstractHealthIndicator.java:82) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator.getHealth(HealthIndicator.java:37) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:81) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.getHealth(HealthEndpoint.java:38) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:108) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:119) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:105) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getAggregateHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:119) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getContribution(HealthEndpointSupport.java:105) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:83) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpointSupport.getHealth(HealthEndpointSupport.java:70) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:75) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint.health(HealthEndpoint.java:65) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.invoke.reflect.ReflectiveOperationInvoker.invoke(ReflectiveOperationInvoker.java:77) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.AbstractDiscoveredOperation.invoke(AbstractDiscoveredOperation.java:60) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:121) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.EndpointMBean.invoke(EndpointMBean.java:96) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:809) ~[na:na]
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1466) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399) ~[na:na]
    at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:827) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor147.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391) ~[na:na]
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]

2020-07-08 18:28:39.955 ERROR 3552 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'TIBCO_TOPIC_NAME' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: authentication failed
2020-07-08 18:28:45.033 ERROR 3552 --- [enerContainer-1] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Could not refresh JMS Connection for destination 'TIBCO_TOPIC_NAME' - retrying using FixedBackOff{interval=5000, currentAttempts=0, maxAttempts=unlimited}. Cause: authentication failed
...
...
...
```

Why is the spring boot application unable to authenticate the connection to the tibco topic even though the username and password is provided via UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter? Do I need to configure anything else?

I am able to connect to this topic and receive messages successfully using the same credentials in a different setup that doesn't use spring boot. And I need to make this work with an existing Spring boot application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to figure out the solution in case anyone else is stuck. In spring boot, TopicConnectionFactory object is not required to specify that we need to connect to a Tibco Topic (and not a Queue), which is needed in standalone application. It is automatically done when PubSubDomain property is set to true. So, use TibjmsConnectionFactory instead which has methods to set credentials. UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter is not needed at all.

I changed my config code to below and it started working!

```
@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class TibcoConfig {

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        TibjmsConnectionFactory factory = new TibjmsConnectionFactory("TIBCO_BROKER_URL");
        factory.setUserName("USERNAME");
        factory.setUserPassword("PASSWORD");
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory jmsListenerContainerFactory() {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setClientId("client1");
        factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
        factory.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Comment: when I'm trying to implement this, intellij complains "Method annotated with @Bean is called directly. Use dependency injection instead." Can you help me out please